# Handling exceptions in xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, exception, xamarin.forms

I've encountered a few dificulties trying to handle some errors in the best way possible. One of my cases for example is NullReferenceException.

To be more clear let me explain it in a few words. When I make a call to a server to receive some pieces of information, in some cases the server might have some problems and it will return of course `null`.

What I've done is I display an alert to let the user know that he can try later again. After this I try to send him in the previous page for example. And after all this my app still crushes.

What I'd like to do is to simply display the alert and then let the user stay in the same page without the application crushing.

These are a few pieces of my code:

tasks.cs

```
 public async Task<List<Idea>> GetIdeaAsync(string accesToken)
  {
      List<Idea> ideas = null;
      try
      {
         var client = new HttpClient();
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesToken);

         var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.getdata.de/api/ideas/");
         var ideas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Idea>>(json);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Server Error", "There has been an server error. Please try later.", "OK");
              if (ideas == null)
              {
                  await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync(); //actually I would like to stay in the same page
              }
      }
      return ideas;
  }
```

view.xaml.cs

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Tasks ts = new Tasks();
    var ideas = await ts.GetIdeasAsync();
    if (ideas == null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("hello");
        //do nothing since the display alert is already shown
    }
    else
    {
      //code here
    }
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can guide me to a "best-practice" approach. Thanks :)

Comment: You are catching fatal exceptions. That is a deadly sin of exception handling. You should propably read up on proper exception handling. Here are two articles I link often that should get you up to speed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: ok @Christopher I will try reading these articles. I guess I need them :)

Comment: Did you try to run that `DisplayAlert` and `PopAsync` inside a `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`? The fatal exception can be caused by accessing the UI thread from secondary ones.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza the exception was not  made by me since it's a fatal exception and I can't do anything to prevent it. In this case there were server problems. My question was the exception handling. Anyway I already solved it so thank for the help .

Comment: Awesome you solved it! Regardless, I'm not sure about _you can't handle or can't do anything to prevent it_. This kind of exception force the app to be stopped, but it's managed by the SO (Android in your case) and it often occurs caused by improper resources accessing. That's what I meant (Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: How can I prevent it if the server which is responsible of giving me some information is down? This is what I meant when I said I can't do anything to prevent it. What I could do is handle the exception of course. (Don't worry it's not my native language either :) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem it was pretty obvious actually since I after catch-ing the exception I would later continue with the code. So what I did was :

```
public async Task<List<Idea>> GetIdeaAsync(string accesToken)
{
  List<Idea> ideas = null;
  try
  {
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesToken);

     var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://www.getdata.de/api/ideas/");
     var ideas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Idea>>(json);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Server Error", "There has been an server error. Please try later.", "OK");
          if (ideas == null)
          {
              //actually I would like to stay in the same page
              return null; //-- added this line 
          }
  }
   return ideas;
}
```

Maybe it's not the best idea but it's working for me. Any other approach would be highly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `ideas` in the try block, and then trying to access it in the `catch` block, where it is out of scope. (Visual Studio should give an Intellisense error)

Also, whenever manipulating the UI, you should always do it on the main thread. so move your `DisplayAlert()` code into

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => 
{
    // await DisplayAlert(); move it into here
});
```

In addition, any `PopAsync` or `PushAsync` calls should also be done on the main UI thread. But calling `PopAsync` after an asynchronous call to an API not be a good idea, as the user may have already pressed the back button by the time the call returns.

As for the NullReferenceException, check to see if `json` is null before passing it to the `DeserializeObject()` function.

Comment: `(await () => `? Did you mean `(async () =>`? I am not sure how any of this answers the question anyway

Comment: @sme the thing this is not my real code just a reproduction. I edited it now, I think it's all good. But anyway I don't see how this answers my question :/

Comment: @John Ok, I understand. In that case, if you want the user to stay on the same page, simply remove the `PopAsync()` call

Comment: I figured that out. The problem is the exception handling. The app crushes since it's a fatal exception. This is the problem in my case